# Supervisor keeps pushing me for a promotion I do not want

Tags: promotion, raise

My supervisor keeps asking me to do the coursework needed for a promotion.  I do not plan on being at the company much longer and have no interest in the promotion.  I kept putting it off, hoping he would forget.  However, that wasnt the case.  He kept on asking about it.  I finally told him that I do not plan on being with the company long term.   I told him the promotion and the meager raise does not interest me.  I have even told him that I am half-heartedly looking for another job.  However, he is still asking me to do it.  Sure, I could just do it and have him stop pestering me, but simply put, I do not want to.  What is the best way to get him to stop asking me, other than my 2 weeks notice?

Comment: @Hoo-Dat Playoc,  Please correct me if I misunderstood your message. Is it true that you have not got a new job offer yet, and you told your manager that you are looking for a new job, and are not interested in any coursework/promotion ? I would recommend that you keep this job until you find a new one. Unfortunately, it's very tough to get a new job in this COVID time.

Comment: Why don't you want the coursework? Couldn't that be potentially usefull at another job? I mean, if he knows you want to leave and still insists you do it, the decision is on him

Comment: How you enrolling in the training benefit your manager? What is his interest?

Answer (score 3):

> I finally told him that I do not plan on being with the company long term ... I have even told him that I am half-heartedly looking for another job.

You have successfully ended your career at this employer and I don't think you can make it any worse.

> What is the best way to get him to stop asking me,

Keep saying: "Sorry, not interested. There is no point in discussing this further" and then move on to the next topic  or just ignore him if he keeps talking. Eventually he'll give up .

Comment: Telling superiors you want to leave isn't always careerending, sometimes they want to keep you and try to change your mind. And sometimes, that even works out. I agree though, that's a risky move unless you know you can trust your manager with that 100%.

Comment: I would add, when you really don't want to do something, don't give any reason at all. I am not interested. Why? because I am not interested. Is there anything we could do to interest you? No. The sentence: "I am not interested" is very strong when used like that, because it's subjective and thus not up to debate. Do no give them an opening by giving any further reason than that.